# Assign an additional parameter to the the C# class object

Tags: c#

I have a method GetProduct, which returns a Product Object and say, i want to return an additional parameter along with the object, how can i implement it? In my below example , how can i return 'isExists '?

```
public Product GetProduct()
{
    ---
    ----
   bool isExists = true
   return new Product();
}
```

I don't want to add that parameter as a property in the Product Class.

Any help on this is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Kan

Answer (score 2):

You could use an out parameter:

```
public Product GetProduct (out bool isExists)
{
    isExists=true;
    return new Product();
}
```

and call is like this:

```
bool isExists;
Product p = GetProduct (out isExists)
```

although it seems to me that `isExists` is the sort of property you might want to have in your Product class...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to rework your method like so:

```
public bool GetProduct(ref Product product)
{
   ---
   ---
   bool isExists = true;
   product = new Product();
   return isExists
}
```

This way you can call the method like so:

```
Product product = null;
if(GetProduct(ref product) {
   //here you can reference the product variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `null`?

```
public Product GetProduct()
{
   bool isExists = true
   if (isExists)
       return new Product();
   else 
       return null;
}
```

And using it:

```
var product = GetProduct();
if (product != null) { ... }  // If exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

Take a look a **Dictionary.TryGetValue** it behaves in a similar manner, if all you need is to return an object from a collection if it exists.

```
Product product;
if (!TryGetProduct(out product))
{
  ...
}

public bool TryGetProduct(out Product product)
{
  bool exists = false;
  product = null;
  ...
  if (exists)
  {
    exists = true;
    product = new Product();
  }   

  return exists;
}
```

If you have other properties you want to return along with the object, you could pass them in as parameters by reference

```
public Product GetProduct(ref Type1 param1, ref Type2 param2...)
{
  param1 = value1;
  param2 = value2;
  return new Product();
}
```

Another option is to group all objects into 1 pre-defined .Net class called **Tuple**

```
public Tuple<Product, Type1, Type2> GetProduct()
{
  return new Tuple<Proudct, Type1, Type2> (new Product(), new Type1(), new Type2());
}
```